# How to refresh Datatable values after selecting drop down value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

According to my requirement i have a dropdown list and when i select a value from the dropdown appropriate data need to be fetch from the database. Dropdown select value sending through jQuery and as Ajax. i have few questions here

1. Do i really want to refresh datatable to be displayed selected data?

Here are the code snappiest.

Dropdown -

```
<select class="filter" id="secquneceDropdownId">
    <option value="" selected>All</option>
    <option value="INSEQUENCE">In Sequence</option>
    <option value="OUTSEQUENCE">Out Sequence</option>
    <option value="RECIPES">Sequence Mapping</option>
</select>
```

jQuery and Ajax call to send dropdown selected value -

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#secquneceDropdownId").change(function() {
            var dropdownSelected = $(this).find(":selected").val()
            var clientID = {
                "isDropdownSelected" : dropdownSelected
            }
            console.log('dropdownSelected value is = ' + dropdownSelected)
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/IdeaOfThings/listSequences",
                data : JSON.stringify(clientID),
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType : "json",

                success : function(data) {

                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Datatable Call for show Data -

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
       var table = $('#example2').DataTable({
            "ordering" : false,
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any link between your `ajax` and `datatable`.

To answer your question 1.

*Yes, you will need to refresh the  grid each time on combo change as Data fetched will depend on the option selected.*

If you are looking for how to implement it

Here is a Sample

```
$("#secquneceDropdownId").change(function() {
    loadData();

}); 


function loadData(){
   var dropdownSelected = $("#secquneceDropdownId").val()
    var clientID = {
        "isDropdownSelected" : dropdownSelected
    }  

    $("#tblDeviceDetail").DataTable({
        "columns": [
           { "data": "ip" },
           { "data": "apiPort" },
           { "data": "hostname" }

           ],
           "ajax": {
               "url": "/IdeaOfThings/listSequences",
               data : JSON.stringify(clientID),
               contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               dataType : "json",
               "type": "POST",
               "dataSrc": "[]",

           }
       });

   }
```

assuming your JSON is like this

```
[ { "ip" : "sfsdsdfs" , "apiPort" : "322",  "hostname": "sfsdfsdf"}, 
{ "ip" : "5345345" , "apiPort" : "4444",  "hostname": "sadfasds"}]
```